# CKEditor image properties not saving

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg, file-manager

I am using the latest version of CKEditor, 3.6.2, combined with FCK's filemanager - followed a tutorial that I found here - http://www.mixedwaves.com/2010/02/integrating-fckeditor-filemanager-in-ckeditor/

Everything seems to be working correctly, however, when I insert an image and, for example, align it to the right this "align" property is not saved through the editor and the image just sits above the text. Other properties not being saved are width and height. Alt **is** being saved.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening to me as well.

In my case it turned out to be an xss-filtering setting in CodeIngniter, which I use as a PHP framework. The way CKEditor posts the image attributes for some reason gets filtered out.

In case you use CodeIgniter as well, this was the fix for me
In /application/config/config.php
Change

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = true;
```

to

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = false;
```

.. and of course make sure you're not using xss_filtering on the form_validation rules in your controller.

Comment: Thank you for the update, I was using Codeigniter and had exactly the same problem which I solved in the same way as you, I forgot to update this post. Thank you for adding to it.